# Can you get several badges at once if you meet the given criteria?

Tags: support, badges

What happens if you meet the criteria for several badges at once? E.g. first comment and whatever, first question. Do you get multiple badges at once or do you have to track a special badge to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do get badges as and when the criterion is fulfilled, irrespective of whether the criteria of multiple badges is fulfilled at once.

Tracking a badge in the profile page is just a way to know the current progress towards achieving it. You don't have to necessarily track badges to get them.

Comment: I already assumed that. Thank you for the information.